# PouchDB's bulkDocs times out after upgrading to 3.2.0 (from 3.1.0)

Tags: javascript, upgrade, pouchdb

I use pouchDB in my tests, and recently upgraded the version from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0. Since then my tests timeout `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded`

Debugging hints at the `pouch.bulidDocs` call never returning (it is trying to insert an array of 20 docs).

I was using the memory adapter, but turned that off to tests and still the tests fail. An upgrade to 3.2.1 didn't fix it, but when I downgrading again to 3.1.0 it all works well.

Is anyone else experiencing similar problems?

Comment: you may want to try the PouchDB forum, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pouchdb

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout using (if you are using Mocha/Chai) `this.timeout(30000)`.

PouchDB 3.2.1 also has some performance improvements, so you may find it is faster than 3.2.0.